# sdl2/sdl.h file is not found

Tags: c++, c++17, sdl-2

When I am trying to make a window using vscode on mac with clang++ I have run into an issue where sdl2 is installed(with home-brew) but vscode cannot find it. This is the error i got in terminal.

```
 *  Executing task: C/C++: clang build active file 

Starting build...
/usr/bin/clang -std=gnu++14 -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g 
/Users/jst_/Coding/VS.Code_C++/Main.CPP -o 
/Users/jst_/Coding/VS.Code_C++/Main
/Users/jst_/Coding/VS.Code_C++/Main.CPP:1:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Build finished with error(s).

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it. 

The code for the window is


#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!window) {
        // Handle window creation failure
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Delay(3000); // Pause for 3 seconds

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

the Tasks json is

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2", // Replace this path with the correct one
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and the C_cpp_properties json is

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/opt/sdl2",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sdl2/2.28.5/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/System/Library/Frameworks",
                "/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I tried multiple times to find different paths i finnaly found the right path but it made no difference i still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the first task in Tasks.json where you compile with clang, you forgot to add the path to the args which is why you are getting the error since you are compiling with clang and in that task the include path (where SDL/sdl2.h is located) is missing.